# Gunzip all the files with a given extension in a different folder

Tags: bash, gunzip

I have a folder with 28 gz files with the extension `.gz` and 28 files with the extension `.gz.bam`.

I would like to unzip all the 28 `.gz` files and send them to another folder. I was doing one by one as follows:

```
gunzip -c file1.gz > /mnt/s3/data_transfer/file1
```

How can I specify I want the .gz and not the .gz.bam?

Comment: Do you really have gzipped bam files? Why? Bam is already compressed, gzipping it won't help.

Comment: They are not Bam @terdon. It was the first file format that came to my mind

Comment: Just to clarify, do you mean `.gz.bam` (what's currently in the question), or `.bam.gz`?

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`:

```
(
  ret=0
  shopt -s nullglob

  for file in *.gz; do
    gunzip < "$file" > /mnt/s3/data_transfer/"${file%.gz}" || ret="$?"
  done
  exit "$ret"
)
```

(also set the `dotglob` option if you also want to process the hidden `.gz` files, those whose name starts with a `.`).

In `zsh`:

```
(
  ret=0
  for file (*.gz(N.)) gunzip < $file > /mnt/s3/data_transfer/$file:r || ret=$?
  exit $ret
)
```

(also adding the `.` glob qualifier to restrict the glob expansion to *regular* files; add the `D` qualifier to process hidden files).

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over them:

```
for file in *gz; do
    gunzip -c -- "$file"  > /mnt/s3/data_transfer/"${file%.gz}"
done
```

The `"${file%.gz}"` is shell syntax that will return the value of `$file` with the final `.gz` removed.

Note that this quick-n-dirty approach is less robust than Stéphane's below, and if you run it in a directory with no `gz` files, it will try to gunzip the `*gz` pattern itself. This won't be a problem as long as you do actually have file names ending in `gz`. Also, unlike his, this one will not exit with a fail status if one of the files fails to be decompressed correctly. If these are problems for you, please use his approach instead.

Comment: By using redirections instead of passing the file name as argument to `gzip`, you also avoid creating the destination file if the source file can't be opened.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas true, sorry, I clarified the exit status. And you're right about the redirection. I still feel a simple approach is worth mentioning since in most cases these things work perfectly well.